# Django behind NGINX reverse proxy and AWS Application Load Balancer doesn't get HTTPS forwarded from client in HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm running Django on Gunicorn behind a NGINX reverse proxy, and an AWS Application Load Balancer. The ALB has 2 listeners. The HTTPS listener forwards to a Target Group in port 80, and the HTTP listener redirects to HTTPS.

[image]

The ALB thus connects with an AWS ECS Cluster, which runs a task with 2 containers: one for the Django app, and another for the NGINX that acts as a reverse proxy for the Django app. Here's the configuration for the NGINX reverse proxy:

```json
upstream django {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

This configuration ensures that whenever the client tries to hit the website app using an HTTP request, he gets redirected to HTTPS. And everything works fine with one exception. In Django, when I run `request.is_secure()` I'm getting `False` instead of `True` as expected. If I run `request.build_absolute_uri()`, I get `http://mywebsite.com` and not `https://mywebsite.com` as expected.

I already tried adding the following lines to `settings.py`:

```py
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

as explained in the documentation, but it doesn't work. Whenever I inspect `request.META` (or the raw `request.headers`), I'm seeing `'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http'` (and the equivalent raw `'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'http'`) instead of `https` as expected. The stack is correctly forwarding `'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST': 'mywebsite.com'` from the client, but the scheme is being ignored.

Can anyone help me identify what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With a Classic ELB you specify the "instance port" (see the listeners tab) and that controls the protocol that you send downstream to nginx. In that scenario it is common to attach an SSL cert to the 443 port but send `HTTP` down port 80 to nginx. the port 80 listener also sends `HTTP`. In that setup, where only `HTTP` is coming in from the load balancer it is your job to inspect the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header and perform a permanent redirect to `HTTPS`. That's because the classic ELB could not redirect `HTTP` to `HTTPS`. With the Application Load Balancer (ALB) I believe you can redirect HTTP to HTTPS if you want to speak 443 to nginx.

In your specific case it seems like you were only listening on Port 80 so you were probably only sending HTTP from the load balancer. Check you Instance Port and protocol.